# Get full path of currently open files

Tags: command-line, python, system, process

I'm trying to code a simple application that must read all currently open files within a certain directory. More specificly, I want to get a list of files open anywhere inside my Documents folder, but I don't want only the processes' IDs or process name, I want the full path of the open file.

The thing is I haven't quite found anything to do that. I couldn't do it neither in linux shell (using ps and lsof commands) nor using python's psutil library. None of these is giving me the information I need, which is only the path of currently open files in a dir.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance,

P.S: I'm tagging this as python question (besides os related tags) because it would be a plus if it could be done using some python library.

Answer (score 0):

The lsof command should work for you. Try

```
lsof | grep cwd
```

where cwd stands for current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there should be a more efficient way of doing this, however this should give you the result you want:

```
lsof -Fn +D $HOME | sed -n '/^n/ s/n//p' | sort -u
```

See this related question on stackoverflow [Check for open files with Python in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20106220).